Helm Upgrade Fails for Sentry: 0 out of 1 Pods Are Running
I am currently working on upgrading my Sentry deployment using Helm, but I am encountering an issue where the upgrade fails, and no pods are running.
Helm Version: v3.14.4
Kubernetes Version: v1.28.9-gke.1289000
When I run the helm upgrade command to apply changes to my Sentry deployment, the upgrade fails with the following error message:
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: dev-sentry/sentry-cron. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: dev-sentry/sentry-cron. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: dev-sentry/sentry-cron. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: dev-sentry/sentry-cron. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
ready.go:303: [debug] Deployment is not ready: dev-sentry/sentry-cron. 0 out of 1 expected pods are ready
UPGRADE FAILED
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:238
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:983
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1115
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.8.0/command.go:1039
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:83
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:267
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650

Could anyone kindly provide guidance on how to achieve a successful helm upgrade to apply my modified values.yaml file changes to Sentry?

can you share more logs from the pod - ```kubectl logs -n dev-sentry $(kubectl get pods -n dev-sentry -l app=sentry-cron -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")

